# since when am I allowed to cast delete votes on questions?

Tags: support, vote-to-delete

I don't have 20k rep, yet today I noticed the `delete` option on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991352/mysql-data-posting-errors-mysqli-query-expects-parameter-1).

[image]

According to the [Trusted User](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) privileges, I shouldn't have this functionality yet.

- Voting to delete answers with score of -1 or lower
- Voting to undelete answers except those deleted by a moderator
- **Voting to delete questions immediately after they are closed (even if they are new)**
- Editing tag wikis without needing approval

I thought the vote to delete privilege doesn't start until 20k?

Comment: Only if the question has been closed for less than 2 days can < 20ks not cast delete votes on questions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Vote to delete* starts with [10k+ rep privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools).*

> You must wait for a question to be closed for 2 days before you can vote for deletion.

With [20k+ rep](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) you can also

- Vote to delete **answers** with score of -1 or lower
- Vote to undelete answers except those deleted by a moderator
- Vote to delete questions **immediately after they are closed** (if they're scored -3 or lower)

<sub>* See the description at the bottom of the page</sub>

Comment: I was under the impression this was only part of the moderation tool. What makes this different from the 20k privileges? Today was the first time I saw this option there.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO The difference is just that with 20K+ rep the user doesn't have to wait.